# could not instance a hashset inside of linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have this Linq and what I tried to do to set the element into the hashset and doesn't work what's missing?? When I debugged the result always show me the property empty

```
var estructura = (from result in query
       select new Estructura()
       {
           IdEstructura = result.Servicio.Campana.Cliente.Direccion.IdDireccion,
           Descripcion = result.Servicio.Campana.Cliente.Direccion.Descripcion,
           lstEstructurasHijos = new HashSet<Estructura>().Select(
            C => new Estructura()
            {
                IdEstructura = result.Servicio.Campana.Cliente.IdCliente,
                Descripcion = result.Servicio.Campana.Cliente.Descripcion,
                lstEstructurasHijos = new HashSet<Estructura>().Select(
                 CA => new Estructura() 
                 { 
                    IdEstructura = result.Servicio.Campana.IdCampana,
                    Descripcion = result.Servicio.Campana.Descripcion,
                    lstEstructurasHijos = new HashSet<Estructura>().Select(
                    S => new Estructura()
                    {
                        IdEstructura = result.Servicio.IdServicio,
                        Descripcion = result.Servicio.Descripcion,
                        lstEstructurasHijos = new HashSet<Estructura>()
                    })
                 })
            })

       });
```

Comment: hi, it's already updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misusing the `select`on the `HashSet` like this one:

```
new HashSet<Estructura>().Select(//... Means take from that new HashSet....
```

Of course a new `HashSet` won't contain anything. This's why you get empty HashSets.

Comment: ok, I understand, but how can I set the values that I want in a hashset

Comment: @Jorge. You have a nasty code over there... =) so it's hard to say exactly without knowing what each line does, but it's should be something like: `lstEstructurasHijos = new HashSet<Estructura>{/*the data */}`